# How can I delete Hudson's built artifacts?

Tags: java, continuous-integration, hudson, operations

We are using Hudson for our Continuous Integration server and it's great. We have 2 issues with it, which are mildly related.

1. https://hudson.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2736 The build order in Hudson means that the downstream dependencies get built a lot more than they need to be. Hopefully this issue will be addressed soon.
2. Since these things are getting built so frequently, the build history is massive. We really don't need 1000 build items in the history for some of the jobs.

My question is about point 2. I would like something like a job or plugin to delete old artifacts. Keeping say the last 20 builds of everything around would be fine. At the moment it seems unbounded, which isn't great from an operations perspective.

UPDATE: As per Norbert's answer, it is in the job configuration. In the 1.300 UI, there is a "Discard Old Builds" checkbox, which allows this to be configured.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is such configuration in our hudson build server. In the project config I can chose between an amount of builds or a period of time to keep. I don't think I installed aplugin for this

Comment: I was looking for this. It was just here, third entry in project configuration... Dynamic configuration is no so great when you scan page instead of reading it :)