# Remove artifacts from Hudson, but retain logs in order to link to builds

Tags: hudson

We have the following requirements for our Hudson setup:

1. We would like to directly link to all builds that have been executed
2. The effective number of artifacts should be limited

It is possible to limit the number of maximum builds in Hudson per job (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805909/how-can-i-delete-hudsons-built-artifacts)). This option effectively removes old artifacts. The problem is that this also removes all other information related to the build.

Is there a way to retain linking directly to completed builds via `http://${hudson}/job/${jobname}/${buildnumber}`, even if artifacts were removed? Sometimes it may be good to commit fixes and link to the corresponding build error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a checkbox under the 'advanced' button when configuring 'archive the artifacts' that allows you to delete all but the most recent artifacts.   The build history is retained, but the artifacts are deleted.

There is an open issue for keeping the artifacts from the last N builds - see [issue 834](https://hudson.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=834)

Comment: Great, I was not sure about that. Now, after your comment I tried it out and it seems to be working. Thank you!