# How to delete unneeded build artifacts in Hudson

Tags: maven-2, hudson

I have a [Hudson CI](http://hudson-ci.org/) server which is building a making a maven build. A parent project with two sub projects. One of maven subprojects creates a rather large .war (10MB) file which is stored for every build. I'd like to get rid of that .war file to save disk space, but I'd like to store everything else the Hudson build stores in history (test results, graphs etc.).

The .war file is stored under `jobs/PROJECT_NAME/modules/PACKAGE_NAME$SUB_PROJECT_NAME/builds/2009-12-23_11-59-11/archive/PACKAGE_NAME/SUB_PROJECT_NAME/1.0/SUB_PROJECT_NAME-1.0.war`

I have tried using job configuration according to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719796/remove-artifacts-from-hudson-but-retain-logs-in-order-to-link-to-builds) namely *Archive the artifacts* and *Discard all but the last successful/stable artifact to save disk space*. But that actually does following:

1. An additional copy is stored for two last build under `jobs/PROJECT_NAME/builds/2009-12-29_17-23-39/archive/PROJECT_NAME/web/target/PROJECT_NAME-web-1.0.war` . So it actually increases disk space consumption a bit.
2. Web page for this hudson jobs contains links to .war files in the two last builds.

My build just executes `clean install` goals against parent *pom.xml*.

So how to configure Hudson server and/or Maven to remove build artifacts automatically from under `jobs/PROJECT_NAME/modules` and leave them under `jobs/PROJECT_NAME/builds`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [post build task](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Post+build+task) to do some files copy/delete stuff.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue a while back, and just went with a cronjob:

```
10 * * * *  find jobs/PROJECT_NAME/modules/ -name "*[tejw]ar" -type f -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Once per hour, it will delete all tar, ear, war, and jar files from this directory (and any subdirectories). There might be a more Hudson-centric way way of doing it...

Answer (score 1):

I came here with a similar question; my issue was resolved with the "Delete Old Builds" checkbox. If you don't care about preserving old build data like the OP does, this checkbox is a simpler solution.

Comment: People, remember to execute the Job, after save it.